# Oauth API client getting Error

Tags: php, oauth

Can anyone tell how I can implement a Oauth api for my site.I have downloaded the example from `http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/downloads/list(oauth-php-175.tar.gz)`

I have created the database and run the register.php file in `example/server` and i got a consumer key and secret key.I have replaced the api key and secret key with this in `client/twolegged.php`.The url mentioned their is replaced with `server/www/hello.php`

But when i run the file `client/twolegged.php` am getting the error

```
ExceptionRequest failed with code 401: Can't verify request, missing oauth_consumer_key or oauth_token-OAuth Verification Failed:
```

Is it the correct way to do this? Please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$server->verifyIfSigned(false)
```

instead of

```
$server->verifyIfSigned()
```

in hello.php